# Excel: Consolidating with VBA for variable worksheets

Tags: excel, vba

I have seen a lot of "consolidating" with VBA on the web, but mostly are copy and pasting from one sheet to another. I am trying to use excel's own consolidating tools, but in VBA. The thing is, the number of sheets can be from 3 to 100. So, it is not quite practical to choose the parameters one by one. Suppose each sheet has the same format, 3 columns. I would like to consolidate the last 2 columns (2 and 3). Each sheet has a specific naming convention, which is some_2015-??, where the last two are digits, in sequential manner (00~99). Consolidating function works admirably, just that needing to specify each range for each sheet is not practical.

Below is the macro I have recorded:

' Selection.Consolidate Sources:=Array("'[Book1]some_2015-01'!C2:C3", _ "'[Book1]some_2015-02'!C2:C3", "'[Book1]some_2015-03'!C2:C3"), Function:=xlSum _ , TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False '

2 questions in total, how do I make the array to adapt to the number of sheets? and I am specifying column B and C, but in the code, it is "C2:C3", does that mean the range is something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
Sub ConsolidateSheets(n As Long)
    Dim A As Variant
    Dim i As Long
    ReDim A(0 To n - 1)
    For i = 0 To n - 1
        A(i) = "'[Book1]some_2015-" & Format(i + 1, "00") & "'!C2:C3"
        Debug.Print A(i)
    Next i
    Selection.Consolidate Sources:=A, Function:=xlSum, TopRow:=True, LeftColumn:=True, CreateLinks:=False
End Sub
```

n = 3 should reproduce your recorded macro. Obviously, `Selection` can be changed if needed. C2:C3 *is* columns B and C in R1C1 notation (which the `Consolidate` method demands). I'm not sure if the book reference is required. It would probably need to be changed if you rename the book. You could try just using

```
A(i) = "some_2015-" & Format(i + 1, "00") & "!C2:C3"
```

Comment: Oh, the R1C1 notation is in Row number and column number. This clears up now. Can I define 'n' as the Activeworkbook.Worksheets.Count if the name starts with some_? Or I will have to rely on creating the summary worksheet after the array has been defined?